# Invalid Keyword Argument error in Django-MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to configure Django with MongoEngine. I have created the models and made necessary changes to my `settings.py` file. However, whenever I try to create a new instance in the python shell, it gives me the same error:

```
TypeError: 'x' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

My `models.py` looks like the listing below:

```
from django.db import models
from mongoengine import *
from gauravgarden.settings import DBNAME

connect(DBNAME)

class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = DateTimeField(required=True)
    event = StringField(max_length=350, required=True)
    notes = ListField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.event


class Extras(models.Model):
    extra_params = StringField(max_length=150, required=True)
    cost = DecimalField(precision=2, rounding="ROUND_DOWN")

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.extra_params

class Itinerary(models.Model):
    booking_date = DateTimeField(required=True)
    customer_name = StringField(max_length=300, required=True)
    plan = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Event'))
    extras = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Extras'))

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.customer_name
```

I am trying to execute the following queries in the `python manage.py shell`.

```
new_event = Event(event_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 30, 11, 30, 00), event = "Welcome/Meet & Greet", notes = ["Hall should be ready", "Keys hand over", "Breakfast layout"])

new_record = Itinerary(booking_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 30, 10, 00, 00), customer_name = "John Diggle", plan = [], extras = [])
```

The error messages says `event_date`, `extras`, `booking_date`, etc are invalid keyword argument for this function.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing Django models with mongoengine fields. You can't do that: if you want to use mongoengine, you need to use their Document class.

```
class Event(Document):
    ...etc...
```